# Xcode Cloud archive timeouts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-cloud

I have been trying to archive my project on Xcode Cloud but getting an error that the project needs more than 120 minutes. How do I increase timeout period or this issue happening because it's still in beta?

[image: screenshot of error from Xcode about actions timing out]